# How to avoid multiple label in zoomin in tilemill

Tags: tilemill, cartocss

Now i am working on tilemill ,and i am facing a problem in a tilemill when i am styling zoomin a road layer that time display road layer label multiple times.
How can avoid disply multiple road layer labels in tilemill.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is possible by using "text-min-padding: undefined;" property. This is somewhat of a hack; It's not the proper way, but the distance between two labels can be manged by setting a value for this property by trial and error.

Comment: Would you be able to re-phrase this part of your answer which does not make much sense to me, please? "But some what we can avoid"